# Share files between projects in VS2010 using Add as link

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to share files between multiple projects in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, so I can reuse some functionality, and not having to manage two separate versions of code.

I tried to add a css file from my first project into the second with : Add existing - Add as link. So far so good, but when I include the css file inside my master page :

```
<link href="../../../Konnektor/Konnektor/WebRole1/StyleSheets/CSS_Backoffice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it is not working inside the browser, because it cannot find the resource, as it is searching for

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/Konnektor/Konnektor/WebRole1/StyleSheets/CSS_Backoffice.css
```

What is the best (better) way to proceed ? Also I suppose that this technique will work when deploying on Azure, because the linked file will be a part of the package ?

Thanks guys